# Swift, Firebase. Checking if name already exist doesn't work

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make an app, where you have to choose a team name, and when the user enter his/hers team name, I want to check if the name already is in use.

teamNameTextField is a `UITextField` and for some reason no matter what I type in the text field, it prints "Team name is not in use". I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, can somebody help me?

My code:

```
rootRef.child("teams").queryOrderedByChild("teamName").queryEqualToValue(teamNameTextField.text).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in

    if (snap.value is NSNull) {
        print("Team name is not in use")
    } else {
        print("Team name is already in use")
    }
})
```

my JSON data tree:

```
{
  "teams" : {
    "pbXvXYOKmJQqwSQZ9IlBykG7x1P2" : {
      "teamName" : "Test111"
    },
    "owidUDkEnbCOsmNSoSFu2o2iu4y38RKJNF" : {
      "teamName" : "Test222"
    },
    "pdnJCDmcdjsiHDFb8349HGD8372bfdhb" : {
      "teamName" : "Test123"
    }
  }
}
```

My database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you hardcode the teamname on your code? like `"Test111"`

Comment: Thank you, you made me realize the problem, I'll answer my own question with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the problem!

I tried to type `print(teamNameTextField.text)`, and it printed: `"Optional("Test111")"`

So you have to put a `!` after `teamNameTextField.text`, then it will only print `"Test111"`